# Scikit learn and data set analysis

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am new to Scikit learn and I tried the first program they have given in their website the code is given below:

```
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import datasets
clf = svm.SVC()
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target
clf.fit(X, y)
```

while I compile the last line I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

pls help me with this issue.

Comment: This code works well just fine. Running just this snippet produces no error at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since the code runs fine in vanilla format. Most likely you have multiple environments interfering. Try running in a new virtualenv.